# How to rewrite the code with ternary operator using typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const contentCards: any[] = sortBy(
    [
        {
            title: 'title1',
            field: //array of objects,
        },
        {    title: 'title2',
             field: //array of objects,
        },
        {
             title: 'title3',
             hidden: true,
             field: //array of objects,
        },
        {
             title: 'title4',
             hidden: true,
             field: //array of objects,
        },
        {
             title: 'title5',
             field: //array of objects,
        },
    ]
);

const contentFields = React.useMemo(() => 
    contentCards.filter(card => {
        const values = card.fields.filter(
            field => getFieldValue(field) !== null
        );
        return (
            !isEmpty(values) && (isSSH ? !card.hidden : true) 
        );
    }),
    [getFieldValue, isSSH]
);


return (
    {!isActive && (
        <FormField label="Content" >
            {() => (
                <>
                    {contentFields.map(card =>
                        //this renders each card
                    )}
                </>
            )}
        </FormField>
    )}
);
```

When `isSSH` and `!isActive`, i want to show all cards except the one with title3 and title 4.

So below is how it should work if

```
!isSSH show all cards
isSSH and isActive show all cards except title3 and title4
isSSH and !isActive dont show any cards.
```

the above contentFields method actually returns all cards if !isSSH  and if isSSH returns all except title3 and title4.

this line in code

```
return (
    !isEmpty(values) && (isSSH ? !card.hidden : true)
);
```

does the filtering of cards based on hidden value.

now to fix this as i want i have changed contentFields method like below,

```
const contentFields = React.useMemo(() =>
    contentCards.filter(card => {
        const values = card.fields.filter(
            field => getFieldValue(field) !== null
        );
        if (!isEmpty(values)) {
            if (!isSSH) return true;
            if (isSSH && !isActive) return !card.hidden;
            if (isSSH && isActive) return false;
        }
    }),
    [getFieldValue, isSSH, isActive]
);
```

the above code works as i want. but could some one help me make this if part of code cleaner. better way of handling it. could someone please help me with this. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `cleaner`?

Comment: Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code looks clean, ternary will look messed up. Here's the ternary verison.

```
!isEmpty(values) && (isSSH ? (isActive ? false : !card.hidden) : true)
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is I can see redundancy in your isEmpty function. You can re-write your function like this:

> ```
> if (!isEmpty(values)) {
>     if (!isSSH) return true;
>     if (!isActive) return !card.hidden; // Executed if(isSSH & !isActive)
>     return false; // Only executed if(isSSH & isActive)
> }
> ```

See, when you are adding a return inside an if(!something) check, then the further code execution will only happen if it will opposite scenario (like - if(something)). So any check for if(something) in further code is redundant.

Edit: I also do not recommend the ternary operator in this case because I believe in the one-line -> one-action philosophy which makes code easier to read and understand during the quick vertical scan.

Edit 2: You will need to return true/false (as per your requirement) outside of the if(!isEmpty(){...}) case. As a practice, you should have consistent returns.

Comment: 100% this, for readability's sake. Much easier to read and future you will thank you.

Comment: you could even forgo the `return false` as the filter's callback would return undefined

Answer (score 0):

Looks close!

```
const contentFields = React.useMemo(() =>
    contentCards.filter(card => {
        const values = card.fields.filter(
            field => getFieldValue(field) !== null
        );

        // You can save some nesting by returning
        // earlier on the `isEmpty` condition.
        if (isEmpty(values)) {
            return false
        }

        if (!isSSH) return true;

        // as you alreay checked for !isSSH, you
        // won't need to do that again below
        if (!isActive) return !card.hidden;

        // As you've already covered !isSSH and !isActive,
        // the last if isn't needed so you only need a return
        return false;
    }),
    [getFieldValue, isSSH, isActive]
);
```